# Can't access hive tables over http

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am trying to use the Hive JDBC driver to connect to the hive server running on a particular host port. I can establish the connection and create tables (the tables also show up on the namenode web UI) but I can't access existing tables. Note: The existing tables were running the hive console and (for some odd reason) can only be accessed when I run the hive console in that particular directory.

How can I get my jdbc client to access the hive tables using the JDBC connection?

Comment: Are you getting any errors while acesing them?

Comment: Just that the table doesn't exist!

Comment: You can try to verify the user with which the tables are created in the jdbc url string. Also, for the tables created, verify the permissions of the folders by viewing them. Since you are able to hit server with jdbc and create, there is not other code issue. I can see only permission issues here.